# Characterization of Bertrand curves by a linear relationship between curvature and torsion

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, curves

Please give a hint for this problem?

> Show a Bertrand curve is characterized by  $\lambda \kappa+\mu \tau=1$ for $\lambda,\mu$ constants, where $\kappa,\tau$ are curvature,  torsion for the curve.

Comment: See Exercise 20 on p. 21 of my (free) differential geometry text, linked in my profile.

Comment: Please provide a definition of a Bertrand curve. Besides, I have taken the liberty to modify your title in order your question is more "attractive" for further searches.